# For-loop index iteration over date vector

Tags: r, loops, date, indexing

I know this is probably a stupid question but why do I need to start from 2 instead of one to get this list to loop properly?

```
date <- seq(as.Date("2021-01-01"), as.Date("2021-12-31"), by="months")
num <- length(date)

for(i in 2:num-1){
    print(paste0("i = ",i))      
  j = i+1
 sd <- date[i]
 ed <- date[i+1]
    print(paste0("start: ",sd))
    print(paste0("end: ",ed))
    }
```

**Output:**

**[1] "i = 1"**

**[1] "start: 2021-05-01"**

[1] "end: 2021-06-01"

[1] "i = 2"

[1] "start: 2021-06-01"

[1] "end: 2021-07-01"

[1] "i = 3"

[1] "start: 2021-07-01"

[1] "end: 2021-08-01"

[1] "i = 4"

[1] "start: 2021-08-01"

[1] "end: 2021-09-01"

[1] "i = 5"

[1] "start: 2021-09-01"

[1] "end: 2021-10-01"

But when I start with: for(i in **1**:num-1)

**It doesn't find the first indexed item properly:**

**[1] "i = 0"**

[1] **"start: "**

[1] "end: 2021-05-01"

[1] "i = 1"

[1] "start: 2021-05-01"

[1] "end: 2021-06-01"

[1] "i = 2"

[1] "start: 2021-06-01"

[1] "end: 2021-07-01"

[1] "i = 3"

[1] "start: 2021-07-01"

[1] "end: 2021-08-01"

[1] "i = 4"

[1] "start: 2021-08-01"

[1] "end: 2021-09-01"

[1] "i = 5"

[1] "start: 2021-09-01"

[1] "end: 2021-10-01"

Comment: Try this `1:(num-1)`

Comment: Well, you haven't described what "proper" execution of the loop might be, but I think it would be informative to compare the results of what you have to those when you define the  loop as `for(i in 1:(num-1))`.  Clue: operator precendence.

Comment: Section 8.1.3 of the R Inferno: https://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf

Comment: @AndreWildberg I think that was it! Didn't realize the order of operations was that way.

Answer (score 0):

Ok So thanks to Andre Wildberg in the comments, I didn't realize there was an implied order of operations within the counter. So this was what worked, using parenthesis to make explicit the desired order of operations:

`1:(num-1)`

instead of

`1:num-1`